# Prove the The Cauchy--Schwarz--Buniakowski inequality using the fact that $E[X]^2 \le E[X^2]$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

So like the title says I want to prove this whole thing. I'm going to paste the whole question here:
[image]

So this is what I have so far:

\begin{align*}
& \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{u_{i}^2}{k} * \frac{v_{i}^2}{u_{i}^2} > \bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{u_{i}^2}{k} * \frac{v_{i}}{u_{i}}\bigg]^2 \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i}^2 * \frac{v_{i}^2}{u_{i}^2} > \bigg[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i}^2 * \frac{v_{i}}{u_{i}}\bigg]^2 \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i}^2 * \frac{v_{i}^2}{u_{i}^2} > \frac{1}{k^2}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i}^2 * \frac{v_{i}}{u_{i}}\bigg]^2 \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} {v_{i}^2} > \frac{1}{k^2}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{i}^2 * \frac{v_{i}}{u_{i}}\bigg]^2 \\\\
\end{align*}

I have no idea where to go from here. Should I stop here and try to plug in some value for $K$? I am super lost and don't even know what an appropriate value of $K$ would be.

Edit: Messed up some Latex lol

Comment: What did you try? Can't you simplify $k$ on both sides? or $u_i^2\frac{v_i}{u_i}$? The choice of $K$ relies on the fact that the sum of the probabilities of all outcomes is $1$.

Comment: @Taladris According to my professor there is only one correct answer for K. I believe that the sum of the probabilities are needed to outcome to 1. Also, yes I did try that and made no progress because I'm not sure how to show that the sum of $v_{i}^2$ > sum of $(u_i * v_i)^2$

Comment: I wrote a solution because I thought the question is interesting. But, honestly, you could have "retro-engineered" the value of $K$ from the formula you had to prove, and do the obvious simplifications.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've never learned about that inequality before this is for a probability class and I didn't know what to expect from the Cauchy-Schwarz, after looking it up I see what you mean. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, but you could have done the simplification $u_i^2\frac{v_i}{u_i}=u_iv_i$ and recognized that the RHS sum is $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$. Also, $\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2=\|\vec{v}\|^2$ and, by multiplying the inequality by $K^2$, you had $K\|\vec{v}\|^2\le (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})^2$. Not hard to find $K$ from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the random variable $X$ whose values are $\frac{v_i}{u_i}$ ($j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$) with probability $p_i=P(X=\frac{v_i}{u_i})=\frac{u_i^2}{K}$. For this to be a probability distribution, we need $p_i\ge 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=1$. This means that $K> 0$ and $K=\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2$.

We have $E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{v_i}{u_i}\frac{u_i^2}{K}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^n {u_iv_i}$ and $E(X^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{v_i^2}{u_i^2}\frac{u_i^2}{K}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2$, therefore

$$
E(X^2)\ge E(X)^2 
\iff
\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 \ge \frac{1}{K^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n {u_iv_i}\right)^2
\iff
K\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 \ge \left(\sum_{i=1}^n {u_iv_i}\right)^2
$$

that is $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2\right) \ge \left(\sum_{i=1}^n {u_iv_i}\right)^2$